# Множественные редиректы htacces

Tags: .htaccess

есть htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://www.test.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ https://www.test.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Открываю несуществующую страницу с ошибкой в адресе получаю несколько редиректов...
как сделать чтобы был 1 редирект?

сейчас

```
http://www.test.ru/documents/test
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.test.ru/documents/test
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.test.ru/documents/test/
```

нужно

```
http://www.test.ru/documents/test
301 Moved Permanently    
https://www.test.ru/documents/test/
```

при этом правила вида

```
 RedirectMatch 301  ^/fitness/$  /services/fitness/
```

или

```
RewriteRule ^fitness/$ services/fitness/ [R=301,L]
```

отправляют на http а не https..

уже все голову сломал. спасибо

Comment: у вас ситуация такова что есть миллион входящих ссылок  с хттп протоколом и оттуда очень много траффика приходит?  Ибо с первым запросом перевели на хттпс, дальше юзера по сайту ходит как обычно. Или у вас на само сайте ссылки целиком прописаны и от этого проблема? Как то не совсем понятна ситуация, с которой вы столкнулись

Comment: @teran У меня например, переехал раздел. я пишу RedirectMatch 301  ^/fitness/$  /services/fitness/, а вместо того чтобы сразу средиректить на https сначала редиректит на http а потом на https - получаю 2 редиректа

Comment: итог - костылили каждый редирект.